# Properties that "lift up" along etale maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, etale-cohomology

I would like to know a list of properties that are known to lift up along an etale morphism. That is, given a ring $R$ with some property $P$, and an etale morphism $A\rightarrow B$, what properties of $A$ can be lifted up to $B$? What about the vice-versa?

For me, an etale map is a finite type flat map with vanishing module of differentials, that is: a finite type flat unramified map.

More than anything, I would like to find a reference that discusses such things. Possibly something more friendly than EGA4 and written in the language of commutative algebra rather than schemes. Strangely enough, I did not find much on stacksproject about this stuff..

Comment: Have you checked the tables at the end of Poonen's [Rational Points](https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf)?

Comment: hmmm thanks for the comment but it seems in those table are only listed references on where to find  about composition and change of base of unramified and etale maps but  I dont think that is what im looking for. And those things already are on the stacks project.

Comment: The only real properties that I generally have used are normal, reduced, and regular. For these see Prop 2.4.4 of Lei Fu's book on etale cohomology. If you want to know what properties you can check along an etale  surjection see this: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02WH

Comment: thanks I'll check on the book! But I dont see the thing you mention about the etale surjections in your link. Or maybe Im not understanding. I followed the links to etale, surjective and unramified but they are not really what Im looking for.. I dont know what does it mean to be fpqc local on the base